# What is the proper alternative for 'credentialize'?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, synonyms

Usage:

> The emergence of a second competitor in the market will help
>   *credentialize* the product and the vision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard phrase in this context is "establish credibility".

Answer (score 5):

[Legitimize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legitimize).

> : to make legitimate

Comment: The product & vision are no doubt legitimate and even otherwise,  cannot be legitimized by competition emerging now.

Comment: In this context, can legitimize not be read as 'conforming to accepted rules/standards/etc' as opposed to 'in accordance with law'? As in, having a second entrant into the market (and running a similar business model/product) means you're both playing by the same rough rules. From a consumer standpoint - one company offering Service X could just be rogue. Two companies offering Service X independently suggests that Service X may be something sensible after all.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[establish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/establish)* (in sense "To prove and cause to be accepted as true; to establish a fact; to demonstrate") and *[accredit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accredit)* (in sense "To put or bring into credit; to invest with credit or authority; to sanction") and their synonyms.

Comment: Both very good, too.

Comment: almost there ...

Comment: Have a doubt with this one. Is *lending credence* and *adding credit* the same? The former is trust and the latter is value, I thought...

Comment: @Shyam: To the extent that "credentialize" is a word at all, I think its meaning would be restricted to the sense of "facilitating the existence / recognition of *credentials*". While such credentials may indirectly convey credit/credence/credibility, I don't think you could stretch the meaning of credentialize to carry that sense.

Answer (score 2):

A little more context would help here, but it sounds like ***validate*** would also work here...if your meaning is "to show that there is a valid need for such a product".